# Employee, first name, last name and ID

Tags: java

I just started and it is really confusing because when I write my code there is no red warning on the eclipse, however when I run the program, it does not work. 
The question is:

> Write a program that displays employee IDs and first and last names of employees. Use two classes. The first class contains the employee data and separate methods to set the IDs and names. The other class creates objects for the employees and uses the objects to call the set methods. Create several employees and display their data.

My codes are:

```
public class Employee {
    String lastName = null; 
    String firstName = null; 
    double ID; 

    public Employee(String lastName, String firstName, double ID){
        this.lastName = lastName; 
        this.firstName = firstName; 
        this.ID = ID; 
    }

    public String empStat(){
        return "Last Name: " + lastName + "First Name: " + firstName + "ID" + ID; 
    }

}
```

and

```
 public class MainEmployee {
   public static void main(String args[]){

   Employee nub1 = new Employee ("Griffin", "Peter", 000001); 
   System.out.println(nub1);
   Employee nub2 = new Employee ("Griffin", "Lois", 000002); 
   System.out.println(nub2);
   Employee nub3 = new Employee ("Griffin", "Stewie", 000003); 
   System.out.println(nub3); 
   Employee nub4 = new Employee ("Griffin", "Brian", 000004); 
   System.out.println(nub4);


 }
}
```

and all it does is display

```
Employee@523ce3f
Employee@71b98cbb
Employee@4cc68351
Employee@7cd76237
```

can someone tell me why?

Comment: Please note: [JavaScript is not JAVA](http://kb.mozillazine.org/JavaScript_is_not_Java)

Comment: Don't get in the habit of zero padding numbers. `000010` is not the number you think it is.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206342/what-is-an-illegal-octal-digit/5206381#5206381

Answer (score 10):

Change

```
public String empStat()
```

to

```
@Override
public String toString()
```

See how `toString()` works (and why you see *Employee@523ce3f*) in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

When you use `System.out.println(nub1);` the method `nub1.toString()` is called implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

One must override the toString() method. This is called any time the object needs to return a string of the object. By default you receive 'Employee@523ce3f' which is an unique internal representation (in string form) of the object.

Simply creating a method that returns String will not do this.

To override the toString() method change:

`public String empStat()`

to

```
@Override
public String toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print objects, it will output hashcode of objects. Printing objects calls `toString()` method in Object class, you must override toString method to get state of objects.

```
public String toString()
{
return firstName+" "+lastName+" "+ ID;
}
```

Overriding `toString` is the easiest approach, consider a list of `<Employee>` type. Printing the list will now return the current field values of objects.

```
List<Employee> list= new ArrayList<Employee>();
Employee o= new Employee("Will","Smith",1);
Employee o1= new Employee("Jason","Bourne",2);
list.add(o);
list.add(o1);
for (Employee x:list)
System.out.print(x);
```

Output:

```
[Will Smith 1, Jason Bourne 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `toString` method a

```
public String toString() {
    return lastName + " " + firstName + " " + Double.toString(ID);
}
```

To put it together:

```
class Employee {
    String lastName = null;
    String firstName = null;
    double ID;

    public Employee(String lastName, String firstName, double ID){
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String empStat(){
        return "Last Name: " + lastName + "First Name: " + firstName + "ID" + ID;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return lastName + " " + firstName + " " + Double.toString(ID);
    }

}
public class MainEmployee {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Employee nub1 = new Employee ("Griffin", "Peter", 000001);
        System.out.println(nub1);
        Employee nub2 = new Employee ("Griffin", "Lois", 000002);
        System.out.println(nub2);
        Employee nub3 = new Employee ("Griffin", "ST", 000003);
        System.out.println(nub3);
        Employee nub4 = new Employee ("Griffin", "Brian", 000004);
        System.out.println(nub4);
    }
}
```

The result is as bellow:

```
Griffin Peter 1.0
Griffin Lois 2.0
Griffin ST 3.0 
Griffin Brian 4.0
```